# Double Shear Stress butt joint

Tags: structural-engineering, stresses, shear

A double shear butt joint is shown below in the diagram 4 plates are held together by two bolts. The applied force is 42KN. Determine the shear stress within the joint

[image]

$$\begin{align}
a &= 2 \frac{\pi}{4} d^2 \\
&= 113.0973355 \\
\frac{42}{2} &= 21 \\
\frac {21}{\pi/4\cdot12} &= 20.05352283\text{ kN/mm}^2
\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: not sure what X is in you first formula.  Also looks like you may have mixed up your order of operations.  Break your answer down into steps.  in a double shear connection, your bolt experiences 1/2 the load of the single member at each side of the single piece.  load is 42 kN /2.  You know stress is a force over an area so then take the load experienced by the bolt at 1 face and divide it by the cross sectional area of the bolt.  Assuming you use mm for the bolt diameter your answer will be in kN/mm^2.    1 kN/mm^2 = 1 GPa.

Comment: @ForwardEd i have changed the question to what you have said. Is this correct now? New to this and trying to learn about it. I have understood the Single Shear, but the double shear and got me a little confused

Comment: you are doubling the area of your bolt, but you should only be looking at one interface at a time.  You bolt needs to have sufficient strength on either side of the single plate.  you check one side then you check the other.  I'd say 99% of the time one side will be equal to the other so you really only need to check the one side.

Comment: So $$ a = \frac{\pi}{4} d^2
= 113.0973355$$ I have changed my answer. Is this correct now? I haven't doubled the bolt diameter.

Comment: I get a value of 185 MPa on the bolt at each slip plane

Comment: you have your order of operation screwed up.  you are doing 21/pi/4*12.  What you need to be doing is 21/(pi/4*12)